# Reference or assembly for class ScreenCaptureJob

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to use

```
ScreenCaptureJob
```

in my application. Google'd and found that this assembly :

```
'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture'
```

is required. But still I am unable to locate this in Add Reference window of .NET Assemblies.
Please suggest how can I get the required assembly for this class:

```
ScreenCaptureJob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to first install all or part of the Expression Studio suite. Then, you can review [the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761462%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) for explicit instructions on using Encoder.

> Before you can use the Expression Encoder OM in Visual Studio, you
>   must add references to the Expression Encoder assemblies. To add the
>   Expression Encoder assemblies in Visual Studio
>
> 1. In Visual Studio, click Project, and then click Add Reference.
> 2. In the Add Reference dialog box, click the .NET tab at the top.
> 3. Press and hold the CTRL key, and then click Microsoft.Expression.Encoder, Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2,
>      Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Types, and
>      Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.
> 4. Click OK.

Answer (score 1):

you need to download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18974) and add it manually to your project